# How to get Visitor IP in magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer

I tried below code to get visitor IP, but it's showing site IP only please tell me how to get visitor IP of the customer,

```
$objectmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$v_ip = $objectmanager->>get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');
echo $v_ip->getRemoteAddress();
```

Comment: you can get same way we get in php like $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: Thanks @ManthanDave, But in magento2 this option is there or not?

Comment: no - AKAIK previously i have tried but its not working so i have used the php way